# React: componentDidUpdate - the previous state is the same like the current state when I update object in array

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in React, and I am missing something...

I have a simple "shopping list" app. I have an array of "product" object (it just has name and amount properties), the user just add products to the list,
and when the user adds a product that already exists in the list, the amount is increased.
So far so good...

So the problem is that I am trying to save the list every time the *componentDidUpdate*, I am checking if the list has changed (I am trying to compare it with the list from the previous state), but when I update product amount, the list from the previous state is the same like the list from the current state (when I add a new product to the list the previous state is not the same).
 Why???

This is the **product** class:

```
export default class product {
    amount = 0;
    name = undefined;
    constructor (name, count) {
        this.name = name;
        if (count)
            this.amount = count;
        else
            this.amount++;
        this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
    }
    addOne = () => {
        console.log(`${this.name} product added one`);
        this.amount++;
    }
}
```

The **adding product** function & **handle duplication** function:

```
    addProduct = (product) => {
            console.log('Add Product - form', product);
            const duplicatedIndex = this.getDuplicationIndex(product);
            if (duplicatedIndex >= 0) {
                this.handleDuplication(duplicatedIndex);
            }
            else { //there is no duplication - just add new product to the list
                this.setState((prevState) => ({ productsList: prevState.productsList.concat([ product ]) }));
            }
}

handleDuplication = (index) => {
        let duplicatedProduct = this.state.productsList[ index ];
        duplicatedProduct.addOne();
        const newList = this.state.productsList;
        this.setState({
            productsList: newList,
        });
    }
```

And the **componentDidUpdate**:

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    console.log('prev', prevState);
    if (!utils.compareLists(this.state.productsList, prevState.productsList)) {
        console.log("saving data");
        const json = JSON.stringify(this.state.productsList);
        localStorage.setItem('productsList', json);
    }
}
```

The **compare lists** function:

```
static compareLists(list1, list2){
        console.log(`list1`, list1);
        console.log('list2', list2);

        if(list1.length !== list2.length)
            return false;
        for(let i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){
            if(list1[i] !== list2[i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So, why does list2 (from the prevState) is the same like list1 (from the current state) when some object is **updated** but they are different when some object is **added** to list1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters --- the compare function is completely unnecessary so long as we handle the state properly.

There are a few issues with state:

(1) Mutating state directly in handleDuplication and addProduct...For more on why this is important read Dave Ceddia's [Why Not to Mutate State Directly](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/https://).
(1.1) React will not do a deep comparison on attribute values for nested properties in an object. When updating the amount and whatnot make sure setting state with the syntax below (again, immutable, make a copy using spread below):

```
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      person: {
        ...prevState.name,
        firstName: "Tom",
        secondName: "Jerry"
      }
    }));

Example above taken from: https://www.rockyourcode.com/react-set-state-with-prev-state-and-object-spread-operator/
```

Below is from your snippet, directly mutating old state. However on further inspection I don't see any need for this given that it's setting the state with whatever the old state list was...Perhaps accidental? In any case could be part of the culprit:

```
     const newList = this.state.productsList;
                this.setState({
                    productsList: newList,
                });
            }

      const newList = this.state.productsList.slice();
            this.setState({
                productsList: newList,
            });
        }
```

Another Potential Change for Product Class:

(1) This makes sure the previous amount is not lost due to adding say two products and then another two of the same product later on.

```
  this.name = name;
        if (count)
            this.amount = **this.amount+=count;**
   this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
    }
    addOne = () => {
        console.log(`${this.name} product added one`);
        **this.amount+=1**;
    }
```

Hope that helps --- Cheers.